# Redirects on firebase with "?" query parametres

Tags: redirect, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to set up redirects domains that contain query parameters. However no mather what i do every url with query parametres are ignored.

Here is an example:

```
  "redirects": [{
          "source" : "/kunstner.php\\?artist_id=10175",
          "destination" : "https://listen.no/?artist=10010",
          "type" : 301
  },
  {
          "source" : "/kunstner.php\\?artist_id=12194",
          "destination" : "https://listen.no/?artist=11998",
          "type" : 301
  }
]
```

These work if i run `firebase serve` and try them locally, however not when i deploy it to firebase.

Comment: The Firebase Hosting CDN currently strips out all query parameters before it hits our origin servers, so unfortunately you can't put query parameters in the "source" of redirects. We're evaluating whether there are workarounds, but have no timeline on when a fix might be possible.

Comment: Good morning @MichaelBleigh, I was wondering if you could use Firebase Hosting as a reverse proxy by redirecting to another domain and keeping URL path and query string ? If not, is it possible to define some route parameters in the source URL that you could use in the destination URL (for example here "source": "/artist/:id", "destination": "https://listen.no/?artist=${id}") ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959652/firebase-hosting-with-dynamic-cloud-functions-rewrites/45224176#45224176