# Creating a catch all redirect & a child function redirect

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

My domain seems to redirect to the index.html and all the sub-links just fine.
Problem is it won't redirect to the api rule `"source": "/api/**"`
I've checked the API manually using the whole firebase url (no custom domain) and it works.

How can I get both domain.com/somelink and domain.com/api/somelink to work in union?

Here's the configuration.

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "api"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try putting the api route after the general route. I think the last matching route wins.

Comment: Already tried this, didn't work.
Do you know if we need to do ```firebase deploy``` each time we want the rules to update?

Comment: I found a fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959652/firebase-hosting-with-dynamic-cloud-functions-rewrites/45224176#45224176

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959652/firebase-hosting-with-dynamic-cloud-functions-rewrites/45224176#45224176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959652/firebase-hosting-with-dynamic-cloud-functions-rewrites/45224176#45224176`

Create a main app which hosts all other top-level functions.

```
const funtions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/users/:userId/:userData/json', (req, res) => {
    // Do App stuff here
}
// A couple more app.get in the same format

// Create "main" function to host all other top-level functions
const main = express();
main.use('/api', app);

exports.main = functions.https.onRequest(main);
```

firebase.json

```
{
    "source": "/api/**", // "**" ensures we include paths such as "/api/users/:userId"
    "function": "main"
}
```

Use the main hook.

```
const hooks = express();
main.use('/hooks/, hooks);
```