# Are query parameters in the "source" of redirects still not allowed?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Are query parameters in the "source" of redirects still not allowed to this date for Firebase?
Answer on [Redirects on firebase with "?" query parametres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981581/redirects-on-firebase-with-query-parametres) states it wasn't, but that was back on 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not supported.  If it was, I would expect to see something specific about it in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config).  The docs all state that the path is what's relevant, not the query string.